# Why the request body is empty in Django when I send a request to it from Node JS?

Tags: node.js, django, django-views, axios, django-forms

I am writing an application using React Native for frontend, Node JS (express, axios) for backend and Python Django (v 4.1.4) for hosting a neural network. In this app I need to send a POST request containing some parameters in body, as well as a music file. This request goes from React to Node JS to Python server. The request is successfully processed on a Node JS server, however, when I send it to Python Django server from Node, I get an empty body in the python endpoint. Now, when Python server is hosted on amazon (I use Elastic Beanstalk), the request comes with populated body, it stops working once I try to host python server locally and send a request from node js to python django server.
You might ask: why bother, just use amazon hosting then? I can't because my neural network is too heavy for free tier hosting and it requires power to respond quickly.
The strangest thing is that requests comes to the Python server (it does not say something like CORS error) and the response is sent from Python server, but the request body is empty.

I have tried to use another IP for Django server (my local one, which is 192.168.1.x) and connect to it from Node: still no body in request.

I have tried to use static global IP for Django server (I hosted on 0.0.0.0 and it was accessible via my globally available static IP). Then I connected to Python server from Node using another network -- so the servers where not in the same LAN. Still the same thing: requests goes, but without a body.

I have tried to use fetch instead of axios -- the same problem.

I am using ALLOWED_HOSTS: "*" for Django hosts setting.

Here's the code on Node JS side:

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('recording', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), req.file.originalname);
form.append('tempo', req.body.tempo);

console.log('requesting', process.env.PYTHON_API);

try {
    const response = await axios.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://83.24.143.208:8000/api/get-notes',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        data: form,
    });
    console.log('response:', response)
    return res
        .status(200)
        .send(JSON.stringify(response.data));
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res
        .status(500)
        .send(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

And this is for Python:

```
@csrf_exempt
def generate_tabs(request):
    try:
        """ PROCESS INPUT DATA GOT FROM THE NODE SERVER """
        file: InMemoryUploadedFile = check_and_fetch(
            key='recording',
            _dict=request.FILES,
            error_msg=f'There is no file with filename = recording. Got the following set of files: {list(request.FILES.keys())}',
            status=404
        )

        tempo = int(check_and_fetch(
            key='tempo',
            _dict=request.POST,
            error_msg=f'Required parameter tempo was not found. Got the following set of keys: {list(request.POST.keys())}',
            status=404
        ))

        file_format = file.name.split('.')[-1]
        if file_format not in ALLOWED_FORMATS:
            raise ProcessingException(
                error_msg=f'File format is inappropriate — WAV and MP3 are supported only. Provided file format is: {file_format}',
                status=415)

        """ STORE PROVIDED FILE, TRANSCRIBE AND RESPOND """
        in_path, out_path, tmp_path = process_file(file, file_format)
        tab_onsets, song_duration = predict(in_path, out_path, tmp_path, predict_config)
        tabs, tacts = get_tabs_for_onsets(tab_onsets, song_duration, tempo, predict_config)
        response = finalize_response(tabs, tacts, song_duration, in_path, out_path)

    except ProcessingException as e:
        response = JsonResponse({"error": e.error_msg}, status=e.status)
    except Exception as e:
        response = JsonResponse({"error": f'There was an error while transcribing the file with the following error message: {e}'},
                            status=500)
    return response


def check_and_fetch(key, _dict, error_msg, status):
    if key not in _dict.keys():
        raise ProcessingException(error_msg=error_msg, status=status)
    return _dict[key]
```

So don't really know what's left to do at all. So, if You have any suggestions/further questions, I will be very grateful for any help, thank You!

Comment: In Django you can have posted data in `request.body` or `request.POST`, are you sure you aren't looking in the wrong area?

Comment: @ViaTech, don't know, but I have added print(request.body) to the python endpoint and this is what I have got: b''

Comment: `api/get-notes` = `def generate_tabs`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, yeap

Comment: I have resolved the issue by using request library (it is deprecated, but still works). So I think it is a problem with axios as it is written here: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789)